# Model is null after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder why the ContactModel in ContactController is not filled with the values provided in the form. Where has my head exploded?

Code as is:

**HomeController (where the contact form is)**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel for Home**

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public ContactModel ContactModel { get; set; }
}
```

**ContactModel to hold the values**

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Index View for HomeController**

```
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactModel.Name, "Name", new { @class = "sr-only" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactModel.Email, "E-mail", new { @class = "sr-only" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactModel.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E-mail" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactModel.Email, "Message", new { @class = "sr-only" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ContactModel.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Message" })
    </div>
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button></p>
}
```

**ContactController Send**

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(ContactModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // ModelState is not valid - but why!?
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Success");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");

    }

}
```

For some reason on my form submit, the model provided in `ContactController.Send(ContactModel model)` has all null values - where is the link broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST action should take the view model as parameter instead of your domain model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(HomeViewModel model)
```

The reason for that is pretty simple - it's the way the default model binder works. Your input fields in the view are all prefixed with `ContactModel`.

Alternatively you could use the `Bind` attribute and explicitly specify that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send([Bind(Prefix = "ContactModel")] ContactModel model)
```

Comment: So the best design if I wish to use the ContactController.Send(ContactModel model) from multiple places, I would move it to some helper class or what is a good design?

Comment: In this case I don't see much benefit of this `HomeViewModel` class that you used in the view. All it does is wrap your domain model in a property which is not how view models are supposed to work.